# Firebase storage uploading images not working on amazon fire(model:Fire 7)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I used to save the image to fire base storage it was working on all android devices but on amazon fire, it was throwing an error.

this is log

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.
```

> E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a
>   RemoteException:
>                                                                       com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zzc: No acceptable
>   module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
>                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyb.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyb.zzi(Unknown Source)
>                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzclq(Unknown Source)
>                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                           at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Exception upload task

> E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
>                                                            android.os.RemoteException
>                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyb.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyb.zzi(Unknown Source)
>                                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzclq(Unknown Source)
>                                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                at com.google.firebase.storage.zzs.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Storage Exception

> E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                  An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner
>   exception for server response.
>                                                                   Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

Does firebase storage work on amazon fire devices?

Comment: What part of `Google Play Store is missing.` is unclear?

Comment: 02-13 10:00:17.066 8713-9028/com.test W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage not found.

Comment: 02-13 10:00:17.068 8713-9028/com.test W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play Store is missing.

Comment: 02-13 10:00:17.068 8713-9028/com.test I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebasestorage:0

Comment: those are the logs i use to get

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase SDKs for Android are built on top of Google Play services, which is linked to the Google Play store.  Amazon devices don't have either of these pieces of software installed on them.

While some Firebase products may work fine without Play services, it is not a guarantee.  The formal prerequisites are listed at [the top of the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).  You're discovering that the Storage SDK actually does not work without Play services.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Services does not come default with Amazon. Therefore Google Firebase Storage will **NOT** work with Amazon without some user action.

From the Amazon Developer page:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/app-submission/migrate-existing-app.html#UnsupportedFeatures

Note that for all of the Google APIs like Maps, In-App Billing, Cloud Message (now Firebase Messaging) Amazon is recommending migrating to Amazon services.

From the Google Firebase Documentation regarding requirements:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

> A device running Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich) or newer, and Google Play services 11.8.0 or higher

Google Play services is required.